# gtkmm.h cannot open source file (but works with pkg-config flags when compiled)

Tags: c++, gtkmm

When I compile my program that uses gtkmm I always have to add pkg-config flags to the command and the `#include<gtkmm.h>` is always underline red (cannot open source file).

How would I be able to get rid of the error and not have to type `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` every time I compile my code, code below:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

void hello_world() {
    std::cout << "Hello world." << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Gtk::Main app(argc, argv);
    auto builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("test.glade");

    Gtk::Window *main_window;
    builder->get_widget("window", main_window);
    Gtk::Button *button1;
    builder->get_widget("button1", button1);

    button1->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&hello_world));

    Gtk::Main::run(*main_window);

}
```

Without the flags I just get the error:

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory
#include <gtkmm.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you typed in your terminal?

```
echo `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

This will display:

```
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/giomm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairomm-1.0/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lglibmm-2.4 -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lgio-2.0 -lcairomm-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

This is all your application needs to be compiled. You can type all these lines by hand but this is not a nice solution because this content depends on your environment and may change pkg-config is here to hide for you the misery.